# How optimize this HTTP connection?

Tags: c#, .net, http, optimization

I'm pretty newbie of C# programming and I'm trying to understand how to optimize this piece of code that is called always into a thread to grab image (snapshot) form an IP camera. I'm trying to make some optimization to make faster the HTTP request but I can't see how and where act. May I ask to experts if there is a way to get this result? Thank you.

```
private Image GetImage()
{

        HttpWebRequest req = null;
        Image img = null;
        HttpWebResponse res = null;

        try
        {
            req = WebRequest.Create(_httpCommand) as HttpWebRequest;
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.PreAuthenticate = true;
            req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_user, _pwd);
            res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            using (Stream rs = res.GetResponseStream())
            {
                img = new Bitmap(rs);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            _status = false; //<<------------------Signaling the FAILURE status! ---

            if (img != null)
                img.Dispose(); //<< for ------GC--------------

            //insert in LOG
            Log logItem = new Log(DateTime.Now, e.Message);
            AddLogItem(logItem);
        }

        return img;
}
```

Comment: you could cache network credentials from what i can see here. apart from that... does it have to be a http request? an actual TCP connection with a steady stream to read from may be way better in terms of performance

Comment: The most important feature to use here is `.KeepAlive=true`

Comment: @EricLaw If you know this for sure you should delete the comment and make it an answer. Judging by the name of it, it seems reasonable.

Comment: @AndreasMüller: It *should* be true by default. The OP hasn't provided any information about what timings he's seeing, nor any headers from the client or server, so the question isn't really in good shape to get good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember, that `HttpWebRequest` will try to determine proxy settings automatically, which takes time.

```
req.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
```

tells it to not use any proxy, thus searching for the correct setting will be skipped.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx